# java create pdf with header and footer

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I'm creating a pdf file (using iText),  and i want to add to each page taht is generated an image at the top left of the page and the page number at center bottom of the page.

How can this be done? examples will be really appritiated.

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: what framework are you using to generate the PDF? iText, PDFBox, other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take A look at the example here : http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ItextExample

There are 2 versions of the same example. The First is from iText2. That is the version I am familiar with, it was very simple to add a header/footer

```
HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter( new Phrase("This is my footer") );
document.setFooter(footer);
```

In the more recent version iText5, this seems to have changed considerably. The link above shows

```
HeaderFooter event = new HeaderFooter();
writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

In this case, instead of HeaderFooter being part of the iText framework, it is a user created class which is extending `PdfPageEventHelper`. So you can change that to whatever you require

Comment: thank's! works greate. just one more question: "ColumnText.showTextAligned" can get only phrase , how can i set it to be with image?

Comment: @user590586 Here is a variation to add a header. This one uses a PdfPTable: http://www.itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=118. see the other examples here http://www.itextpdf.com/book/examples.php

Comment: Try this one as well http://www.itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104  In either example, PdfPtable is used, that class has the method addCell() which can take a type Image

Answer (score 1):

You want to extend com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper and implement the following:

```
public void onStartPage(PdfWriter pdfwriter, Document document)

public void onEndPage(PdfWriter pdfwriter, Document document)
```

Then set the page event on your PdfWriter:

```
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
pdfWriter.setPageEvent(new YourPageEventClassGoesHere());
```